# c++-setting an array that accepts a list of values

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How do i set the following :

```
wxArrayString numberArray;
numberArray.Add(wxT("1"));
numberArray.Add(wxT("2"));
numberArray.Add(wxT("3"));
numberArray.Add(wxT("4"));
numberArray.Add(wxT("5"));
numberArray.Add(wxT("6"));
numberArray.Add(wxT("7"));
numberArray.Add(wxT("8"));
numberArray.Add(wxT("9"));
```

not as writing everything specificlly but something like 1-9 so that this number array has everything from 1-9 , excluding 0 .

Thanks

Comment: Is this a unicode build, non-unicode, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Add numbers 1-9 to numberArray
wxArrayString numberArray;

for (size_t i = 1; i <= 9; ++i)
    numberArray.Add(wxString::Format(wxT("%d"), i));

// Display content of numberArray
for (size_t i = 0; i < numberArray.size(); ++i)
    wxLogDebug(numberArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you want the array to only accept a certain set of data? If you, you can create a class like this:

```
class MyArray
{
    //your accepted data will be stored in this vector.
    std::vector<int> data;

    //the acceptable values will be stored in this set. 
    std::set<int> acceptable;

    public:
        MyArray()
        {
            // in the constructor we fill the set.
            for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
                acceptable.insert(i);
        }
        void add(int item)
        {
            // if the set contains the item you want to insert, then insert it
            if(acceptable.find(item) != acceptable.end())
            {
                data.push_back(item);
                std::cout<<"Added";
            }
            // else throw error or simply don't add it.
            else
            {
                std::cout<<"Not acceptable";
            }
        }
};
```

If i completely misunderstood you, then sorry! Just tell me and i remove the answer if it is irrelevant!